# Absolute scrollable div inside flex container without fixed height, is it possible?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I set a div as scrollable (absolute) without fixed height filling entire view, while inside a flex-box?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tgAj.jpg)
(typo at the right section, its fixed width, the only height expected is to be fullpage everything)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJyOOp?editors=1000
(if I add height to the relative parent of the red section, it works, but I cant have a fixed height. Adding 100% from html to the relative parent also works, but I can't also do that.)

currently it goes:

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <div style="flex-grow:1">
        <div style="display:flex">
            <div style="width:45px...">
                ....
            </div>

            <div ...header code>
                ....
            </div>

            <div style="flex-grow:1; top:70px; position: relative">
                <div style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom: 0; overflow: auto>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div style="width:45px...">
       ....
   </div>
</div>
```

It ends up filling the header height.

Comment: Your chances of a response will greatly increase if you replicate your model in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), so it's easy for everyone to troubleshoot.

Comment: Added a codepen

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the idea of absolute content if its not necesarry and try something similiar to:

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.sidebar{
  background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

.contentWrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
      flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

.scrollableContent {
    height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="scrollableContent">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where you basically make every container a flex and the non scalable part of its content will have fix width/height and the other part get `flex: 1` which is shorthand for taking rest of the space.